# ASP.NET GridView Cell Editing alternative

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Is it possible to edit and update a GridView cell without using

`<asp:TemplateField>` and/or

`<%# Eval("Name") %>` and/or

`<%# Bind("Name") %>` and/or

SqlDataSource ?

NB : I want to use only C# code in the behind and SqlConnection, SqlCommand, ExecuteXXX, etc.

NB : Plz provide me code(C# and aspx) or a web-link containing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't figure out why are  you fighting against asp.net, but you can do what you want using *ObjectDataSource*. The *ObjectDataSource* control uses reflection to call methods of a business object to select, update, insert, and delete data. You set the *ObjectDataSource* control's *TypeName* property to specify the name of the class to use as a source object.

Working with *ObjectDataSource* resume to do things like:

**To Declare it:**

```
<asp:objectdatasource
  runat="server"
  id="ObjectDataSource1"
  typename="EmployeeLogic"
  selectmethod="GetAllEmployees"
  updatemethod="UpdateEmployeeInfo"
  dataobjecttypename="NorthwindEmployee" />
```

**To Create Methods into code-behind:**

```
public List<NorthwindEmployee>GetAllEmployees()
{
 //your code here
}
public void UpdateEmployeeInfo(NorthwindEmployee emp) {
 //your code here
}
```

to Configure the GridView and to be happy :)

Below I've provided some links that might help you:

http://www.manuelabadia.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,c72852ae-1fdd-4934-a715-f565ceaf21cc.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57hkzhy5.aspx

http://www.google.com.br/search?hl=en-us&q=objectdatasource+asp.net

Comment: Coz I am from C# Winforms background.

Answer (score 2):

Use `onrowediting` and `onrowupdating` in gridview markup...
something like this:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="5" DataKeyNames="Id"
    onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
    onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing">
```

I am not very sure about winforms, but in websites try this..

```
 protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    //your code that will edit/update.

}
```

In general, code with `Sqlcommand` and `Sqlconnection` will be something like:

```
 SqlConnection con;
SqlCommand cmd;
DataSet ds;
SqlDataAdapter da;


 protected DataSet FillDataSet()
{
    string source = "Database=GridTest;Server=Localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes";
    con = new SqlConnection(source);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_mygrid", con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    return ds;


}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also need to eliminate SqlDataSource and Use Winforms style SqlCommand, SqlCennection, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution maybe is to manage the RowDataBound event of the gridview and set the values like

```
e.Row.Cells(i).Text = value
```